# how to resolve this : Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')"?

Tags: java, class, spring-boot, exception

i'm working on simple **project** that implement 
*spring security*.
the issue come when i tried to work with Logout link with *Spring* and *Thymeleaf*.

1.pom.xml

```
    <!--Spring Boot Dependencies  - Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependencies Spring Security-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

navbar.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!--<li><a th:href="@{/login}" th:text="#{navbar.login.text}"></a></li>-->
                <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
                    <a th:href="@{/login}" th:text="#{navbar.login.text}"/>
                </li>
                <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
                    <form id="f" th:action="@{/logout}" method="post" role="form" class="navbar-form">
                        <button type="submit" th:text="#{navbar.logout.text}" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

error scrrenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens when the Thymeleaf Extras Spring Security version is not compatible with the Spring Framework version, in its case, the Spring Boot version works with the Spring Framework version 5.x and the Thymeleaf Extras Spring Security version you have is 4.x. You need update the artifactId in your pom.xml and either choose a compatible version or let Spring Boot choose the version for you

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```